# After adding Pli_Layer Price Filter Extension, CMS content is not displaying

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am using Magento 1.8. After adding Pli_Layer Price Filter Extension for slider filter, CMS content is not displaying on front end.

I am using this extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magi-price-slider.html

Comment: there are any errors dispaying on front end or a blank page displaying???

Comment: No.. There is no error is showing..